# MWPhotoBrowser - how to force to select just one photo on selection mode?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mwphotobrowser

I am using MWPhotoBrowser in my app.

I just need to force to select only one photo on selection mode.

Is there any way or tip we can implement that functionality?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if you want single image selection only then  image picker controller can do this. why are you using the MWPhotoBrowser ?

Comment: Single image selection from a remote location? Thank you, i'll search about that...

Comment: Have you found any good option for this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bring the following changes in the implementation of delegate method of MWPhotoBrowser.

```
- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index selectedChanged:(BOOL)selected {
    for (int i=0;i<selectedPhotos.count;i++)
    {
        [selectedPhotos replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
    [selectedPhotos replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:selected]];
}
```